# Calling an object as a function as well as calling a function inside of that object

Tags: javascript

I'd like someone to confirm for me that it's impossible to create an object that allows me to make both of the following calls in javascript:

```
user.remove();
user.remove.all();
```

Comment: nothing is impossible with javascript :)

Comment: I'm learning that to be the case!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can.  Here is an example.

```
            var user = new Object();
            user.remove = function () {
                console.log("remove called");
            }
            user.remove.all = function (){
                console.log("remove all");
            }

            user.remove();
            user.remove.all();
```

Answer (score 0):

No it's not impossible. functions are objects just like everything else. There is nothing to stop you doing the following:

```
function User() {
    var remover = function (){
        // do removal stuff 
    }

    remover.all = function () {
        // do remove all stuff
    } 

    this.remover = remover;
}
```

Then just create the user as normal:

```
var user = new User();
```